# Mobile device managment for SAFE devices

Tags: android, mdm, device-admin

I am trying to develop a Mobile Device Management Application. I have so far implemented native or basic restrictions (policies) based on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Now I want more access to the device to put more restrictions, I searched and found a page which is almost exactly same for what I want to implement. Below is the page:
http://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/help/mobile_device_management/mdm_android_restrictions.html

I understand that almost all of these require the device to be SAFE. Once I have the SAFE device then where can I find any documentation or source code or samples where I can see how these restrictions are getting implemented in code. I am unable to find any such thing so far. There must be some API or tutorials etc to guide on implementing these. 
Please guide me on how to implement these on SAFE device.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register to [Samsung Safe program.](http://www.samsung.com/us/business/samsung-for-enterprise/) As soon as you will be member you will have access to

- Documentation
- Examples
- Special API token which will allow you to call these API's

Comment: How can I register? I can't find any such option on the site your provided. Also, my device is Prestigio-MultiPad-10.1 on which AirWatch was running previously. And all the restrictions were in action which I mentioned in my question. 
Only Samsung devices can be SAFE or can my Prestigio-Multipad be SAFE as well?

Comment: I am not sure. Take a look at this page: http://www.samsungmobileb2b.com/partner/seap/faq/list.do

Comment: Anyways thanks for your help. Up voting the answer :)